# All text files copied to my pc have encoding problems

Tags: windows, encoding

No matter what their origin, if I copy/download a text file to my PC, polish characters are replaced by some weird ones. I've tried converting the files to different encodings, but it was not of much help. What's weird is that when I open the file on a different PC before copying it to mine, the file displays just fine. What can I do about it?
I'm on Windows 7 32-bit;

Comment: What kind of file? What software are you using create/view these files?

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution. I had to change the default language for non-unicode programs to Polish in Control Panel->Region and Language->Administrative->Change System Locale. I have no clue why it would affect how files with set encoding are displayed in Notepad or as video subtitles, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

For ordinary .txt files, try explicitly setting an encoding when saving them (Unicode (UTF-16LE) or UTF-8 using notepad).